# How to render a component passed inside another component's parameter

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to render this:

```
<%= render MyProj.SnippetView, "doc_ready.html",
        state: "DOMContentLoaded",
        func: "setTimeout(function(){
                        #{render(MyProj.SnippetView, "scroll_page.html",
                            type: nil,
                            offset: -75,
                            target: @scrollTo,
                            duration: nil)}
                        }, 1)"
    %>
```

but I'm getting errors:

```
protocol String.Chars not implemented for {:safe, [[[[[[[[["" | "var scrollOffset = "], "" | "-75"] | ";\nvar scrollTarget = "], [["" | "$(\"#"] | "imgasEmpresas16"] | "\").offset().top + scrollOffset"] | ";\n$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollTarget"] | ""] | "}, \n "], "" | "1"] | ");"]}
```

Is that because I cannot do it or because I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{:safe, iodata}` is Phoenix's way to mark a string as safe to print without escaping characters like `<`, `>` and `&` to prevent XSS. You can convert the `{:safe, _}` term to an `iodata` which can be used in a string interpolation using `Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata/1`:

```
<%= render MyProj.SnippetView, "doc_ready.html",
        state: "DOMContentLoaded",
        func: "setTimeout(function(){
                        #{render(MyProj.SnippetView, "scroll_page.html",
                            type: nil,
                            offset: -75,
                            target: @scrollTo,
                            duration: nil) |> Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata}
                        }, 1)"
%>
```